# Programmatically get the central administration site SPWeb using server object model

Tags: development, 2013, central-administration, object-model

Like in the title - is there a method of getting it without supplying the URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rafal,

You can use:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication centralWeb =
SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local;
```

Comment: you was first :)

Comment: :) you explained it better!